# Cannot instantiate DataSource

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I am trying to make a DataSource object just as mentioned in documentation: [Apache Tomcat 8.5 Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html#Code_Example) Code example.

My code is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

/**
 * Class for encapsulating data connection and retrieving.
 * @author George
 *
 */
public class DataConnector {

    private static final String USERNAME = "root";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "store_db";

    public DataConnector(){
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/" + DATABASE_NAME);
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        p.setUsername(USERNAME);
        p.setPassword(PASSWORD);

        DataSource ds = new DataSource();

    }

}
```

But it gives the following error: Cannot instantiate the type DataSource.
Any suggestions why?

Comment: Because DataSource is an interface. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html?is-external=true.

Comment: @JBNizet can you explain then why is that used in example code in the link I mentioned above.

Comment: There is no such example in the page you linked to.

Comment: @JBNizet please go to Code Example -> Plain Ol' Java.

Comment: How about linking to the correct page. There is no Plain Ol' Java code example in that page.

Comment: The code uses `import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;`. Your code uses `import javax.sql.DataSource;`. Not the same class.

Comment: @JBNizet Alright. Worked it. Thanks a lot. Will you write an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code uses `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`, which is not the same class as the one you're using: `javax.sql.DataSource`.